# Send result back multiple activities and finish except first activity

Tags: android

I need the flow of Activty4 Pass the data to Activity1 and close all the activities  except Activity1.

```
Activity1-> open Activity2(it has tabview)
Activity2-> open Activity3
Activity3-> Pass the data to Activity1 and also close Activity2 and Activity3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On activity1 use the `startActivityForResult` call to start the activity2 so you can get the result of it:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

On activity2:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 2);
```

On activity3 at the point you set the result:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

This sets the result and closes Activity3 with the call to `finish`.

Now, on Activity2 you should add this code to get the result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 2) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("result", result); // send the result of Activity3
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}
```

And you can get the result on Activity1:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result = data.getStringExtra("result"); // Now you have the result here
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}
```

Notice you should get consistent with the integers you set on the startActivityForResult and the requestCode you receive, I recommend using constants here.

If you need more info have a look at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result
and [How to manage startActivityForResult on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

1. IMHO the best choice is using `Observable` pattern.
2. `Activity 4` has an `observable` object, `Activity 1,2,3` will be registered to `observe` it.
3. When the data in `Activity 4` is ready, `Activity 4` will send a signal to **notify** that data has been ready then `Activity 1 will receive the data` and `activity 2 & 3 will kill itself`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is following
Whenever you wish to exit all open activities over another activity you can do it in this way

Do this in 3rd activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("your_params","param"); // data
startActivity(intent);
```

And in First Activity, in oncreate handle intent

```
 getIntent().getStringExtra("your_params");
```

If OnCreate don't get called, please override onNewIntent method

```
 @Override
 public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    getIntent().getStringExtra("your_params");
}
```